# How to set new attribute to a @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, html, .net, razor, dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to add an specific attribute (data-toggle="select") to my DropDownListFor.

When I use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model, myList, "Select..", new { @class = "form-control", @data-toggle="select" }).
```

I get the error saying that "Cannot resolve symbol 'data'" and "Cannot resolve symbol 'toggle'"

What can I do so my DropDownListFor recognizes the attribute data-toggle?

Ps: When I use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model, myList, "Select..", new { @class = "form-control"})
```

it works just fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is actually pretty simple, just replace your -(dash) with a _(underscore) and you will be set.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model, myList, "Select..", new { @class = "form-control", @data_toggle="select" }).
```